# ATMA on OBDII not Working

Tags: obd-ii, can-bus, elm-327

I have successfully connected a terminal android app to the obd port of my car. And tried dry run of many at commands, many are working as expected.

But ATMA (AT command to Monitor All) is not responding. Trying to view all the can communication.

Whenever this command is sent via terminal app, the response provided is OK and then again prompt for next command.

Any thing i am missing here?

edit1-
car is ford figo diesel model, connected to ELM327 using this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ges.bluetooth.hyperterminal&hl=en)

Comment: You are going to need to add more information about your car and the tools you are using.

Comment: Is there any update after a year? I'm in the same situation with a bluetooth elm327 clone which works for any other AT command.

Comment: The elm device was a cheap duplicate, try using another device. The sofware version by my device was shown as 2.1 but i believe thats exaggerated.

Answer (score 8):

Did you set the protocol for the chip to monitor on? e.g. ATSP5 for KWP-2000 or ATSP0 for "best guess". What about checking the headers as well - ATH1?

I use the following string of commands to monitor my full KWP bus, which is obviously different from CAN, but is similar enough that it might be of use:

`ATI` -- check connection from app to scan tool

`ATH1` -- Print headers

`ATAL` -- Allow "long" messages ( > 7 bytes)

`ATSP0` (or `ATSPX`, where X is the protocol number) -- Sets the protocol. 0 is "guess"

`ATMA` -- Monitor all

You may have also bought a clone of the ELM327 chip - I have found, from personal experience, that a lot of the cheap clones do not offer the full command set. It would have to be a very very bad clone for it not to suppose ATMA!

Comment: all commands executed but no luck - http://imgur.com/oQbs3SZ

Comment: ATAL has been part of core ELM327 commands since version 1.0, so the ? after you run the command - to me - would indicate a cheap knockoff. This would also explain ATMA not doing what it's suppose to.

If it's a real ELM327 chip, you should get something back from `at@1` and `at@2`.

Out of interest, how much did you pay for the scan tool? If only a few bucks, it's probably a fake - wholesale price of an ELM327 chip alone is about 10 USD.

Comment: Addendum: I had very similar problems to you wrt cheap knockoffs. I got two different bluetooth scanners from a well known cheap site, and both of them only support subsets of the commands (and poorly at that). One of them didn't support warmup messages and the other one wouldn't support setting the headers. Oddly enough, the USB scanner I got from the same site, whilst a clone, supported all the commands I needed... the mind boggles.

Comment: seems like mine is cheap clone with basic functionality. @1 and @2 commands are provided with response.

Comment: I have an original OBDLink adapter. ATMA neither works with K-Line nor with plain CAN protocol (not ISO15765) I strongly recommend to use a J2534 adapter instead (Tactrix) These ELM adapters are hobbyist adapters and full of bugs. The Tactrix has the big advantage that the intelligence is in the controlling software on the PC rather than in a processor with buggy firmware in the adapter. The ELM327 adapters are a misdesign. Read my comments on https://netcult.ch/elmue/hud%20ecu%20hacker/